# Regex for splitting string when numbers are encountered

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split

i have a set of strings i would like to split for example,

```
'id 1'
'photoid 90'
'classid 02'
'numbers of sibling 3'
```

i want them to split using regex like them

```
    ['id', 1]
    ['photoid', 90]
    ['classid', 2]
['number of sibling', 3]
```

Comment: so split on space?

Comment: no i  want 'numbers of sibling 3' --> ['number of sibling', 3] this too

Comment: So reg exp match numbers followed by end of line.

Comment: Yaa basically..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matching group that matches anything, followed by a space, followed by one or more numbers, followed by end of line. [visualize it](https://regexper.com/#%2F%28.*%29%5Cs%28%5Cd%2B%29%24%2F)

```js
var str = 'numbers of sibling 3';
var match = str.match(/(.*)\s(\d+)$/);
var result = [match[1], +match[2]];
console.log(result);
```